# Add a new item to a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am not quite sure my question really has something to do with `listview`.There is an app named [Gleeo Time Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.gridvision.pbtm.androidtimerecorder) ,and [here](http://www.google.com.hk/imgres?q=gleeo%20time%20track&um=1&hl=zh-CN&newwindow=1&safe=strict&tbm=isch&tbnid=PUrX5ft8YVFxgM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.anzhuo99.com/ruanjian/shenghuobibei/13098.html&docid=eVjMwaba6aL74M&imgurl=http://www.anzhuo99.com/jimi168/320x480/10/097/312/1314000333376.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=19STT6-qFuG5iQf9-OygBA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=295&sig=102663670689591432708&page=1&tbnh=154&tbnw=103&start=0&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:66&tx=61&ty=114&biw=1366&bih=673) has a screenview of it.When you press the symbol `"+"`,a new item will be created,and you can delete one item by pressing the `"-"`.More is that when I click the record button on the left of the item,the background will change.

My question is,what is it in the end,a listview? How can I achieve such thing?Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is build a custom ListView.
This is done by providing a layout file, for example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/Plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is then applied to each row of your ListView by overriding its Adapter's getView() method, for example something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);  
            }    
            ImageView plus = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            icon.setImageDrawable(BrowseActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.Browse_FileName);

// add a listener to your button and you're done

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

read about list view in developer docs and here is an [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)