# Android: How to put an image file from sd card to HashMap with simpleadapter?

Tags: android, image, listview, hashmap, simplecursoradapter

I am reading files from the selected folder on my phone like you can see in the following code. 
And how could I get this work with an Imagefile?
At the end I like to have an imagelist with a preview of every image. 
Like that:

[IMG] (imgview) - [Filename] (String)

```
        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {

        File file = files[i];
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
            path.add(file.getPath());

            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                map.put("img_list", ""+R.drawable.folder);
                map.put("string_cell", file.getName()+"/");
                your_array_list.add(map);

            }else{


                ImageFileFilter filefilter = new ImageFileFilter(file);

                if(filefilter.accept(file)){
                   //Its an imagefile

                    // ==> I like to replace the ""+R.drawable.image with the file that I have read
                    map.put("img_list", ""+R.drawable.image);


                } else {

                    //Its not an image file

                }

                map.put("string_cell", file.getName());
                your_array_list.add(map);

            }
        } 


    }

        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, your_array_list, R.layout.connected_upload_row,
            new String[] {"img_list", "string_cell"}, new int[] {R.id.img_list, R.id.string_cell});
list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

In the following picture I like to replace the white "image" picture with the original picture called "41786486733.jpg" as preview.
So that the user can see what picture this is...

[image]

**EDIT FLORIAN PILZ**

```
if(filefilter.accept(file)){

                    Log.v("PATH1", file.getPath() );


                    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_list);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    myImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp); 



                }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to implement a custom listview, see an example here [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267103/add-a-new-item-to-a-listview/10267200#10267200

Comment: why u are creating HashMap instance two time `map = new HashMap<String, String>();` remove last one

Comment: puzzler i am working with a custon listview ;)
ρяσѕρєя every time when you have to reinizialize the HashMap otherwise it's not working...

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : put `map = new HashMap<String, String>();` after ` File file = files[i];` inside for loop and remove` map = new HashMap<String, String>();`  from every where and plz tell me clearly what is current issue you are phasing

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя I added a picutre in my Question for explaining what I want to have. Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : if you want to add images from sdcard as imageview src then first you will need to convert it to Bitmap and then use setImageBitmap for adding to imageview

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224710/set-imageview-to-show-image-in-sdcard

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : create an custom adapter by extended baseadapter class instead of SimpleAdapter . as i think this will be easy or also you can create more custom UI instead of using inbuild

Comment: It's not working with the Bitmap method... It won't display a picture just the filename and the checkbox. `if(filefilter.accept(file)){
         ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_list);   
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
         Log.v("PATH", file.getAbsolutePath() );
         img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
         
         // ==> I like to replace the ""+R.drawable.image with a local image file
           // map.put("img_list", ""+R.drawable.image);
         
            
        }`

Comment: I don't know how to create a custom adapter... DOesn't it work with SimpleAdapter?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20761/discussion-between--k-and-marco-seiz)

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : you hve done or still facing same issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K The problem still exists...

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : what issue  you are still facing?

Comment: @MarcoSeiz : can you join me on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20761/discussion-between--k-and-marco-seiz

Comment: Answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874644/how-to-show-thumbnail-from-image-path

Comment: Problem has been solved.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874644/how-to-show-thumbnail-from-image-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for my problem is here:

[How to show thumbnail from image path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874644/how-to-show-thumbnail-from-image-path)

I had to create a customlistview (with help from  ρяσѕρєя K) THANKS!!

***create an custom adapter by extended baseadapter class instead of SimpleAdapter . as i think this will be easy or also you can create more custom UI instead of using inbuild***

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the picture, and assuming that the white image with the text "IMAGE" is an ImageView instance, then simply...

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Or did I completely misunderstood your question.
Anyhow this [small example](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html) tries to do something similar, what your are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is not working... When I do it with your code the images are empty and it looks like the second picture in my edited answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question with an answer accepted. Check: [Cannot open image file stored in sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563365/cannot-open-image-file-stored-in-sdcard)

Snippet from there:

```
File directory = new File(extStorageDirectory, "myFolder");
File fileInDirectory = new File(directory, files[which]);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileInDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Try to sent to log this: fileInDirectory.getAbsolutePath() if it's correct check if the image is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement custom listview check this [example](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.in/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html) and seem  storing path in hashmap creating issue,it will more helpful if you provide error log cat! anyhow  can you try below trick to achieve you goal instead storing path in hashmap?,hope it will help to you.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePath()+"/Folder/");

    file imageList[] = file.listFiles();

     for(int i=0;i<imageList.length;i++)
     {
       Log.e("Image: "+i+": path", imageList[i].getAbsolutePath());

       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageList[i].getAbsolutePath());
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```